# Is it true that $\bigcup_{a\in A}\{f(a)\}=f(A)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets with arbitrary elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, and let $f:A\to B$ be a function. Further, let $f(A)=\{b\in B:b=f(a)\text{ for some }a\in A\}$ be the image of the function $f:A\to B$. **Is the following statement true?**

\begin{gather}
\bigcup_{a\in A}\{f(a)\}= f(A)
\end{gather}

**[EDIT] ATTEMPT**: I believe the answer to be ‘yes’ because:
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{a\in A}\{f(a)\}&=\{b\in B:b=f(a)\text{ for some }a\in A\}\\
&=\{f(a):a\in A\}\\
&=f(A)
\end{align}

Comment: what do you think ? what have you tried ?

Comment: Please, use $=$ and not $\equiv$; they are *sets*.

Comment: @Surb Thank you for your comment. I thought the answer was yes, but apparently is no…

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question. Could you please give some guidance on when is the use of “$\equiv$” acceptable?

Comment: Usually, we have *equality* ($=$) between "objects", like sets, and equivalence ($\equiv$) between statements (see prop logic).

Comment: Re your last point in the comment below: $f(A)$ is a *set*: the set of values of function $f$ for "inputs" from set $A$, while $f(a)$ is a single element: the value of $f$ for input $a$. The operation $\bigcup$ is on sets; thus, we have to consider the sets $\{ f(a) \}$ and "collect" them all together for all $a$'s in set $A$ in order to have an "equation" (here why the equal sign) between sets.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is my understanding from your comment and AlvinL’s answer that despite the statement $\bigcup_{a\in A}\{f(a)\}=f(A)$ is correct, the statement $\bigcup_{a\in A}f(a)=f(A)$ is incorrect becase $f(a)$ is not a set but $\{f(a)\}$ is. Also, it is my understanding that if the function $f:A\to 2^B$ mapped to the power set of $B$ (i.e., $2^B$) rather than to $B$ itself, the expression $\bigcup_{a\in A}f(a)=f(A)$ would be true because $f(a)$ would be a subset of $B$ and therefore a set. Correct?

Comment: @Héctor The initial statement is false, because $\bigcup f(a)$ is ill defined. It cannot be equal to what is on the RHS. Roughly speaking, two objects are equal only if they are the same kind of object. So if on one side you have a set, then you need to have a set on the other side of $=$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial statement $\bigcup _{a\in A}f(a) = f(A)$ is false. On the RHS is a subset of $B$. The LHS is some ill defined collection of symbols. You should, instead, try to prove the equality
$$ \bigcup _{a\in A}\{f(a)\} = f(A). $$

---

You might think that assuming $f(a)$ is a set for every $a\in A$ saves the day. Well now you have a new problem. Without getting too technical, I'll just give an example.

Put $A =\{a,b\}$ and $B = \{ \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}\}$. Let $f(a) = \{1,2\}$ and $f(b) = \{3,4\}$. Then
$$ \bigcup f(a) = \{1,2,3,4\} \quad\mbox{and}\quad f(A) = B.  $$
There is no equality.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have two questions: (1) could you please explain why your notation is right and mine is wrong (I don’t see it)? Also, (2) is the statement you’re suggesting me to prove true or false?

Comment: @Héctor Set theoretic operations can be done with , let's call them, cardboard boxes. If $f(a) = \textbf{"cat"}$, then it's not a cardboard box, is it? On the other hand, you could put it into a cardboard box (i.e $\{f(a)\}$). For now it suffices to understand this difference.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I don’t see the relation between your comment and my question.

Comment: @Héctor union is defined for sets and only sets. $f(a)$ can be anything, a number, a matrix, and so on.

Comment: If we let $f(a)$ be a set, then the expression $\bigcup_{a\in A}f(a)=f(A)$ is true, whereas the expression $\bigcup_{a\in A}\{f(a)\}=f(A)$ is correct regardless of the nature of $f(a)$. Yes?

Comment: @Héctor The first half of your comment does not work.

Comment: Why doesn’t? Suppose that $f:A\to 2^B$, where $2^B$ is the power set of $B$. Then, $f(a)$ is a set, isn’t it?

Comment: Your post starts with "let $f : A \to B$ be a function". You cannot then change your mind and suppose instead that $f : A \to 2^B$ without abusing notation.

Comment: @AlvinL: My comment was addressed to the immediately preceding comment by the OP.

Comment: @LeeMosher my mistake

Comment: Thank you. Your edit made me understand your point.